# Black screen in vmware after rebooting

Tags: server, windows-7, vmware, reboot

I have installed Ubuntu Server 11.10 in VMmware (Running in a windows 7 machine).
Everything went fine for the first time but now i cant start it.

I started Vmware, then it appears the purple ubuntu screen and after then everything goes black with the cursor blinking.

I have tried to re-create the Virtual Machine and the problem remains.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This is a seeming bug with Ubuntu server. The work around is to change to another virtual terminal (console).

Normally one would Ctrl+alt+F2

With vmware try

> CMD + OPT + CTL + F2

If F2 does not work , try F1 or F3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and did not find a solution online either. What worked for me was that I reinstalled the display manager, and reconfigured lightdm to be the default display manager when rebooting. Terminal should still be accessible through [ctrl + alt + F2].